# Need to create ad report using facebook API

Tags: python, api, facebook-graph-api

In the marketing API there is an endpoint for downloading ad report like graph.facebook.com/{ad-report-run-id}/insights

How we get the ad report run id? Or Do we need to post a job for creating a ad report?

Please need advise on this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices#asynchronous

Comment: Thanks for your help. The articles shows the steps to achieve the result.